# How to get powershell script parameter list using c#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I need a c# code that can list parameter information for a given script. for e.g. it takes the path for a script and should list names of all parameters and if the parameter is optional or required.

Is this possible?

Adding more info:
I'm looking for something like the below cmdlet in c#. An api that returns a formatted output which cn be parsed easily.

Get-Help MyScript.ps1 -Parameter *

Answer (score 2):

From C#, you can invoke the PowerShell engine in order to execute PowerShell code.  There are plenty of examples in SO that show how to invoke PowerShell commands from C#. The command you want to invoke is:

```
Get-Command <path-to-ps1>
```

The result will be a `System.Management.Automation.ExternalScriptInfo` object.  Inspect it Parameters and ParameterSets properties for the information you required.

Comment: I don't care the question is ambiguous; this answer is what I was looking for. I'm working on a C# tool that executes PS scripts. I need the user to enter parameter values through its front-end without knowing the script content up front. So I read the Parameters collection to dynamically build the front-end. I have only one question: how can I identify user-defined parameters in the collection (without having to enumerate each of the CommonParameters)?